# FiddlerCore session timeout

Tags: c#, session, fiddler, session-timeout, fiddlercore

I'm handling local requests by using FiddlerCore. All sessions are queued in `Queue<Session>` and processed by a `BackgroundWorker`. After the process is done, I would like to send a response, indicating the success or failure of the processing, by using the processed session. The problem is that I'm getting the **Too late, we're already talking to the server** error.

This is the FiddlerCore function:

```
private static void FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest(Session session)
{
    if (session.hostname.ToLower() == "localhost")
    {
        LogHelper.WriteFormat("Local request {0} enqueued", session.id);
        sessionsQueue.Enqueue(session);

        if (!sessionWorker.IsBusy)
            sessionWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

This is the thread function:

```
private static void sessionWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (sessionsQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        if (sessionWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            sessionsQueue.Clear();
            LogHelper.Write("Shutting down, all requests canceled");
            break;
        }

        currentSession = sessionsQueue.Dequeue();
        LogHelper.WriteFormat("Processing request ID {0}", currentSession.id);
        ProcessSession();
    }
}
```

This is the code at the end of the `ProcessSession` function:

```
{
...        
    currentSession.bBufferResponse = true;
    currentSession.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
    currentSession.oResponse.headers.HTTPResponseStatus = "200 OK";
    currentSession.oResponse["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    currentSession.oResponse["Cache-Control"] = "private, max-age=0";
    currentSession.utilSetResponseBody(responseBody);
}
```

I've tried to tamper with the session's timers and state, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception in question occurs when you call `utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer` after having already sent the request to the server. If you want to use the `utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer` method, you must do so *inside* the `BeforeRequest` handler, not at some future time. Similarly, setting `bBufferResponse` after having already connected to the server is pointless.

Based on your later remarks, you have a misunderstanding about how threading works with FiddlerCore. FiddlerCore processes Sessions on background threadpool threads.

- When `BeforeRequest` fires, your code has a chance to run. If you call `utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer` inside that method, then the response you generate is **immediately** returned to the client.
- If you don't call `utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer` inside `BeforeRequest`, the request is immediately sent to the server by FiddlerCore, and the response is returned to the client when it's available.

To achieve what you're describing, you should NOT try to do your own threading-- instead do all of your work on the thread that goes into the BeforeRequest method and don't leave that method without generating the desired response. You don't need to worry about hanging the UI or anything like that, because `BeforeRequest` is running on a background thread. The only thing you must do is the `Invoke` methods if any of your code needs to interact with any UI owned by the UI thread.

Comment: I would like to get a request, send the request body to a printer and send a response rather the printing is successful. I got a queue that accumulate the requests, a backgroundworker thread that takes each request from the queue, print its body and should send a response to the request initiator. I've tried to call the utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer function in the BeforeRequest handler and send the response after the printing is done but then I see no body in the response in the browser.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how FiddlerCore works. BeforeRequest fires and your code has a chance to run. If you call `utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer` then the response you generate is immediately returned to the client. If you don't, then the request is sent to the server by FiddlerCore, and the response is returned to the client when it's available. To achieve what you're describing, you should NOT try to do your own threading-- instead do all of your work on the thread that goes into the BeforeRequest method and don't leave that method without generating the desired response.

Comment: I was worried about how much load the BeforeRequest function can handle. Isn't there a way to accumulate the sessions, process them one after another and return a response to the initiator? How can I stop the request from being sent to the server, yet send a response to the browser when I'm done with it?

Comment: You should follow the steps I've laid out. If you have a problem with those, we can then discuss that.

Comment: I didn't encountered a problem with your method, so I'm checking this as the answer, thanks.